# PHP loop sum values with two keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sum, key

I have a loop in PHP, more or less it have result like this

```
$items = array(
    [menu_id] => 10, [current_price] => 150, [num] => 10 ,
    [menu_id] => 12, [current_price] => 200, [num] => 20 ,
    [menu_id] => 10, [current_price] => 150, [num] => 30 ,
    [menu_id] => 11, [current_price] => 100, [num] => 40 ,
    [menu_id] => 11, [current_price] => 100, [num] => 50 ,
    [menu_id] => 11, [current_price] => 200, [num] => 60 ,
    [menu_id] => 13, [current_price] => 300, [num] => 70 ,
) ;
```

How to make a new array of it by adding the values of num if they have same menu_id and current_price?
I expect result like this ...

```
$new_items = array(
    [menu_id] => 10, [current_price] => 150, [num] => 40 ,
    [menu_id] => 11, [current_price] => 100, [num] => 90 ,
    [menu_id] => 11, [current_price] => 200, [num] => 60 ,
    [menu_id] => 12, [current_price] => 200, [num] => 20 ,
    [menu_id] => 13, [current_price] => 300, [num] => 70 ,
) ;
```

Please help :)

I did tried this,

```
      $tmp = array();
      foreach ($items as $obj) {
          if ( (!in_array($obj->menu_id,array_keys($tmp))) && (!in_array($obj->current_price,array_keys($tmp))) ) {
              $tmp [$obj -> menu_id] = (object)array (
                  'menu_id' => $obj->menu_id,
                  'current_price' => $obj->current_price,
                  'combine_num' => $obj->combine_num,
              ) ;
          } else {
              $tmp [$obj -> menu_id] -> combine_num += $obj -> combine_num ;
          }
      }
      $test = array_values($tmp) ;


      $i = 1 ;
      foreach ($new_items as $key) {
        print_r($i++);echo( '::' );
        print_r($key);echo('<br/>');
      }
```

But I end up on combine and count it with same menu only, I dunno how to bind the current_price also ... Please help :)

Comment: As you said... You do it by adding the num values if they have the same menu_id and current_price. What "loop" did you try?

Comment: edited ... please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach as

```
$grouped = [];
foreach($items as $v){
$index = $v['menu_id'].'-'.$v['current_price'];
 isset($grouped[$index]) ? ($grouped[$index]['num'] += $v['num']) : ($grouped[$index] = $v);
}
print_r($grouped);
```

You can use `array_values` to re arrange the array keys.

Example :- https://3v4l.org/MYEYO